# How to subscribe component load event in blazor?

Tags: components, blazor

Could someone help me how to handle when a component is loaded?

I want to make an event handler for loaded. Is there is any loaded
event in the component base in blazor or do I have to implement everything as I wanted?

Comment: Have you read - [Blazor Component lifecyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/blazor-for-web-forms-developers/components#component-lifecycle).  If so then perhaps a little code would be helpful to show what you want to do with a Loaded event?

Comment: What I am thinking is that if componentbase of blazor doesn't provide the event for loaded then I will make my own event loaded. And I will also make the event handler in the parent component as the way I handle in the wpf or winform.

Comment: "Loaded" is a bit of a loose definition.  You need to define what you mean by loaded.   Do you mean when the component has completed `SetParametersAsync`?  Or when the component is rendered? Or?

Comment: I have done with wpf this type of event handling. I am not sure about  blazor. Loaded means after rendered.

Comment: Consider: Initialise => async load the data=> render with some info about loading => Finish loading the data => render with real data.   There are two render events.  This is a normal common scenario.  See Henk's diagram below.  [Polite] You need to consider why you need it?  Why is what you are doing so unique that it doesn't already exist?

Comment: No offense, but if you haven't learned about `OnInitialized` yet, you haven't studied Blazor at all.  You need to watch some YouTube videos or go through https://blazor-university.com/

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 - the OP wants to handle it in the Parent component.

Comment: @Henk Holterman maybe I have a reading comprehension problem I guess.  The guy said "Loaded means after rendered," and there's an OnAfterRendered component event.  I should be less snarky until I fully understand what someone's talking about, maybe. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [this picture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-5.0#lifecycle-events):

[image]

The concept of "Loaded" is not so clear but the end on Onitialized would be the best spot. The parameters are set, including your callback event.

But do consider, why would you need this?  It is not customary. Components are easier to use when they are independent, even more so in a Web app.